# how to change an attribute value after clicking swatches based on sku in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, swatches, configurable-swatches

i want to change an attribute value based on swatches selection for example based on swatches selection the SKU gets changes so how to change an attribute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to change value of sku on base of option selection:

Step 1: (override class using `di.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data" type="<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Helper\Data"/>

    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="xnotifConfigurable" type="<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Step 2 : `Helper/data.php`

```
<?php
namespace <VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

/**
 * Class Data
 * Helper class for getting options
 *
 */
class Data extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data
{
    /**
     * Catalog Image Helper
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    protected $_productloader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    )
    {        
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($imageHelper);
    }

    public function getOptionsSkus($currentProduct, $allowedProducts)
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $productDetail = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
            $sku = $productDetail->getSku();
            $options['sku'][$productId][] = $sku;
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Step 3: (`..\Type\Configurable.php`)

```
<?php
namespace <VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Product\View\Type;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Configurable
{
    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;
    protected $swatchHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        \<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Helper\Data $swatchHelper
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Composes configuration for js
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $currentProduct = $subject->getProduct();
        $sku = $this->swatchHelper->getOptionsSkus($currentProduct, $subject->getAllowProducts());
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);
        $config['sku'] = isset($sku['sku']) ? $sku['sku'] : [];
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }  
}
```

Step 4: (Override `swatch-renderer.js` into your module or theme)

initialize selector for sku in $.widget.options as

```
selectorProductSku: '<sku selector>',
```

call this function OnClick() & OnChange() function:

```
$widget._SetSkus(childProductId);
```

add this function:

```
    /**
     * Update sku
     *
     * @private
     */
    SetSkus: function (childId) {
        var $widget = this,
            $product = $widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct),
            childId = this.getProduct(),
            $productSku = $product.find(this.options.selectorProductSku),
            sku;
        if(childId) 
        {
            sku = this.options.jsonConfig.sku[childId][0];

            var skuSelect =  $productsku.find("<sku selector where to point>");
            $skuSelect.html(sku);
        }
    },
```

Hope it will help you. Contact if have any query!

Comment: Hi Ronak, I used the slight similar approach from your code. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: If this is the correct way then you can make it correct so it can be helpful to others